# Adding XML Tag inside a Tag [Maximo Automation Scripts]

Tags: soap, response, integration, maximo, inbound

Does anyone there knows how to put a tag inside a tag for MAXIMO Automation scripts for integration inbound response?

like this:

```
 <OUTSIDETAG>
     <INSIDETAG>VALUE HERE</INSIDETAG>
 </OUTSIDETAG>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the version you are using. I believe scripts capabilities were extended starting 7.6 (also 7.5.0.6 IIRC). 
You could override tags content with a function

```
def overrideValues(ctx):
if ctx.getMboName()=='PO' and ctx.getMbo().isNull("description")==True:
ctx.overrideCol("DESCRIPTION","PO "+ctx.getMbo().getString("ponum"))
```

Here is a document describing this in detail - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/02db2a84-fc66-4667-b760-54e495526ec1/page/03ad118c-6040-43dd-bc6d-d7a03510d135/attachment/1004fd2b-1b51-411e-8df0-a8b02ca86272/media/Scritping76Features%20%285%29.pdf